# Run shell commands from browser

Tags: command-line, firefox

I'd like to access the terminal from Firefox specifically.  I only have access to firefox, I can't access terminal on its own.

Comment: This is not possible for security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this by default. No page-level element has access to anything like that and the standard chrome (the interface, not the competing browser) is fairly locked down.

However there are plugins. Chrome-level elements *can* access and fork out commands. To do this you'll either need to write your own Firefox-based terminal emulator or use something like [commandrun](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/commandrun/).

I'm sort of assuming this is a kiosk machine you're trying to break. If it is, and whoever owns it has done their job, you're not going to be able to install a random plugin (that would be pretty awful security!) so this just isn't going to work.